# str_replace returns empty string after replace

Tags: php, replace

I am trying to replace my custom short codes, but function **str_replace** return empty.

I have a fixed list of search.

```
$search = array(15) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "{{user_name}}"
  [1]=>
  string(17) "{{ticket_number}}"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "{{ticket_link}}"
  [3]=>
  string(18) "{{ticket_subject}}"
  [4]=>
  string(22) "{{ticket_description}}"
}

$replace = array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(23) "ticket with attachments"
}


$subject = string(20) "{{ticket_subject}}"

echo str_replace($search, $replace, trim($subject));
```

Why the result is empty?

Comment: php docs said: `If replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values.` both arrays need the same size and order.

Comment: That's  invalid PHP code. Make `$replace` a string if you want all elements from `$search` replaced with the same string

Comment: If I can to solve my example of code in another way?

Comment: `both arrays need the same size and order`...should give you enough information to solve it. Or see brombeer's answer which already has an alternative approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `$replace` a string if you want all elements from `$search` replaced with the same string.

From [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php): "*If **search** is an array and **replace** is a string, then this replacement string is used for every value of **search**.*"

```
<?php
$search = [
    "{{user_name}}",
    "{{ticket_number}}",
    "{{ticket_link}}",
    "{{ticket_subject}}",
    "{{ticket_description}}",
];
$replace = "ticket with attachments";
$subject = "{{ticket_subject}}";
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

Edit: different approach using array:

```
<?php
$replacements = [
    "{{user_name}}" => 'Roman',
    "{{ticket_number}}" => 1234567890,
    "{{ticket_link}}" => 'url.com',
    "{{ticket_subject}}" => 'Hello World',
    "{{ticket_description}}" => 'foo bar',
];

$search = array_keys($replacements);
$replace = array_values($replacements);

$subject = "Dear {{user_name}}, we received your ticket #{{ticket_number}} with subject {{ticket_subject}}({{ticket_description}}). As a reminder, {{user_name}}, please close your ticket #{{ticket_number}}";
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

will output:

Dear Roman, we received your ticket #1234567890 with subject Hello World(foo bar). As a reminder, Roman, please close your ticket #1234567890

Comment: brombeer, I had a dynamic replace values .. it can be one element or 10 element.. it depends of  subject.

Comment: That's crucial information that should have been mentioned in your question in the first place.

Comment: If you "_have a fixed list of search_" how would you replace those 5 items with 10 elements? Please explain _in your question_ what the different cases can be.

Comment: brombeer, yes I have a fixed list of search but in replace array element can be repeated several times. In subject I can have 2 ticket_number and 3 ticket_subject for example .. it is like email template with dynamic subject but fixed search.

Comment: Not sure I can follow. I doesn't make sense (to me) to have _more_ __replacement__ elements than elements to __search__ for. Make sure they are at least the same size. Multiple `{{ticket_subject}}` in your `$subject` string will be replaced with the same element from `$replace`

Comment: brombeer, I have a subject for example... user {{user_name}} has created ticket with number {{ticket_number}}. The search always the same, but subject always different. In subject I can use the same custom short code several times. For example user {{user_name}} and user {{user_name}} has created ticket with number {{ticket_number}} and number {{ticket_number}}

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I added an example using arrays. Please post _in your question_ two examples that explain your problem, I can't seem to follow, sorry.

Comment: How to solve such problem if both arrays not the same size and order not the same?

Comment: Bring them in the correct order then. Make them the same size unless you want empty replacements. As already stated, having _more_ replacements than strings to search for makes no sense. I won't ask you a third time to post examples in your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

According to the PHP documentation:

> If replace has fewer values than search, then an empty string is used for the rest of replacement values

Your search array has more values than your replace array.

(https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Bert Bijn, thank you very much. If I can to solve my example of code in another way?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve, but you should just put 5 items in your replace array